# Using the Expected value of the log as a score for the anomaly detection instead of just the expected value

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-network, autoencoders, variational-bayes

While dealing with anomaly detection using a probabilistic model I need to compute the probability of an example coming out of the model I built. More specifically:
If $p(X)$ is the model I built and trained from my data, I need to compute the reconstruction probability of an outlier taking into account the latent variable of my model (just for clarity, I'm using a Variational Autoencoder).
If $\hat{x}$ is an outlier I expect the reconstruction probability to be low, since it does not come from the model.
$reconstruction\_prob = E_{z}[p(x)]$ where $z$ is the latent variable.

This idea is taken from this paper: http://dm.snu.ac.kr/static/docs/TR/SNUDM-TR-2015-03.pdf
and referenced is this other paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03903 (section 3.3).

All of these papers proceed to say that instead of using $E_{z}[p(x)]$ it is more convenient to use $E_{z}[log(p(x))]$.
This would be great news but I can't prove that:
Being $x,y$ two examples,

if:

$E_z[p(x)] < E_z[p(y)]$

then:

$E_z[log(p(x))] < E_z[log(p(y))]$
which I guess is what I need in order to use $E_z[log(p(x))]$ as a reconstruction "probability"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Convenience as such is not a mathematical property, so I don't know if there is anything to prove here. However, there are advantages to taking logs. In a complex model, the probability of any particular outcome will typically be small. Taking logs can prevent an underflow error.

Furthermore, if there are independent components in your model, $p(x)$ will factor into components, so taking logs will turn the product into a sum.